# I'm trying to reverse a number by using a recursive in c language but the output is not changing

Tags: c, function, recursion, reverse

```
#include <stdio.h>
int rev(int num);
int main()
{
int num=123;
printf("\n%d",rev(num)/10);
    return 0;
}
int rev(int num)
{
    if(num==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((num%10)+rev(num/10))*10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a hint how you think your function works? From my point of view it splits the digits and builds the number together in the same order and adds a `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
long reverse(int n) {
   static int r = 0;
   
   if (n == 0)
      return 0;
   
   r = r * 10;
   r = r + n % 10;
   reverse(n/10);
   return r;
}
```

in each iteration you take the once digit added to the static r and multiply the result with 10,
and call the recursive function with the number without this digit `n/10`

Comment: Ok but do you have any idea why my code is not working